# Why EFI images require some extra padding before the PE/COFF header

Tags: image, linker, portable-executable, osdev, uefi

Every EFI image I've inspected has at least `40h` bytes of padding between the MS-DOS stub and the PE signature which is unused in some cases. It's filled with zeros.

I'm writing a linker and my first plan was to have 0 padding in the specified location but it seems that the UEFI loader simply stopped responding after loading the file. I've tried some weird combinations like merging the DOS header and the PE header into one location but the same problem occurred.

I also tried entirely removing the DOS-stub and for some reason my firmware was still able to recognize the image too. Usually, if the image doesn't start with the `MZ` signature, the loader prints error messages and exits. I'm sure that in this case, it's parsing directly the COFF format properly because after writing the invalid Magic value for the optional header, the loader recognizes that and prints the error message. The problem is that it still bugs out and prints nothing. It just hangs. Is parsing the PE header like this normal. Could I count on it to work on other machines?

I'm sure that otherwise the image is fully working. Even if it wasn't, when there is a padding, the loader prints the error message and exits instead of just hanging. If the image is loaded and executed successfully, it should print the `Hello World` message. This happens when the `10h` padding is present and everything began to work perfectly. How do I accomplish such a task? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check this [reference implementation code](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/MdePkg/Library/BasePeCoffLib/BasePeCoff.c) to have the same bug.
You can also use TE images to have all unneeded headers stripped disregard of their lengths.

Comment: I can't exactly see the bug. Maybe you can be more specific. Also are you sure TE images are guaranteed to be supported by the UEFI firmware?

Comment: I also can't spot the bug, but IBVs can use a slightly different implementations, and a bug may be there. What I meant is that's possibly not a problem of all the UEFI implementations, just your one.
As for TE images, they are normally used for PEI modules, and it's not a popular solution for DXE drivers and UEFI applications, that's why I'm not sure that it's supported in this particular case.

Comment: What information do you actually fill in?